# In Next.js, how can I update React Context state with data from getServerSideProps?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

I'm having a lot of trouble learning to properly load data into state in my todo app.

I have a next.js page component `pages/index.tsx` where I load data from my API via `getServerSideProps` and return it as a page prop called `tasksData`.

The `tasksData` is being returned properly and I can access them in my page component just fine via prop destructuring: `const Home = ({ tasksData }: Home) => { }`

I also have a React Context provider in `_app.tsx` called `BoardProvider`. This stores state for my task board, and employs `useReducer()` from the React Context API to update this state in context consumers, such as `pages/index.tsx`.

The challenge I am facing is how to make my UI's "source of truth" the *state stored in my context provider* (eg. `const { { tasks }, dispatch } = useBoard();`, rather than the page page props returned from my API (eg. the `tasksData` prop).

One approach I considered was to simply load the data in `getServerSideProps` and then set the state via a dispatched action in a `useEffect` hook:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // On first render only, set the Context Provider state with data from my page props.
  dispatch({ type: TaskAction.SET_TASKS, payload: tasksData });
});
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working because sometimes `tasksData` is `undefined`, presumably because Next.js has not yet made it available on page mount.

Another [suggestion](https://twitter.com/kochakian/status/1462122021727264771) I heard was to fetch the data and pass it as `pageProps` to my Context Provider in `_app.tsx`. I believe this means using `getInitialProps()` in `_app.tsx` so that my provider's initial state is populated by my API. However, this disabled static optimization and other useful features.

Can anyone help me out with some pseudocode, documentation, or examples of how to use `getServerSideProps` in combination with React Context API?

Comment: Why don't you set the tasks when you first fetch the data?

Comment: @SILENT I'm unable to do this because React Hooks cannot be used serverside in Next.js `getServerSideProps().` If that were possible, it'd definitely be the ideal solution!

Comment: You can fetch data via `getServerSideProps` and pass it to the respective page. If the page detects it as `undefined`, the page should fetch it. However, you mentioned todos. Todos are multi-tenant (ie user / organization specific). You shouldn't load this type of data server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of points:

1. `getServerSideProps` should be invoked before the page is even rendered. So theoretically your `tasksData` is `undefined` is a bug! You can't have a server data to be unavailable unless you really really intend to have that happen in the first place.
2. Assuming `getServerSideProps` is always returning the right data, but you want to use your own data to override it. In your context, you can have this logic.

```
  const Home = ({ tasksData }) => {
    const value = { tasksData: {
      // let me override it
    }}
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={value}>
      ...
      <Context.Provider>
    )
  }
```

If you have the `context` provided under a page, the above code is all you need. But if your context is provided in a root (parent of a page), you can still add the above code to re-provide the same context again with overridden value. Because this is how a `context` is designed, read https://javascript.plainenglish.io/react-context-is-a-global-variable-b4b049812028 for more info.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for,
I did not knew it was this simple; XD
Thanks